# Можно ли как-то Input выражать как псевдоэлемент?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Например в ::before будет как поле ввода или ползунок

Comment: К сожалению, нет

Comment: Input на то он и Input, что он явный элемент управления. Псевдо он никогда не будет...

Comment: Для какой задачи? Возможно можно заменить `input` на какой-то другой тег, который может использовать псевдоэлементы.